# Cannot run Webmatrix? I get a Web PageInspector error

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

Previously I had Webmatrix, Visual C# Express and Visual Web Developer Express on my machine. I updated Microsoft Visual Studio Express and now I get **ASP.NET failed starting up** when trying to load Webmatrix:
This is the error message:
**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have uninstalled Webmatrix and re-installed it. Also I removed Visual Web Developer.
This Visual Studio Web.PageInspector does not belong to Webmatrix I believe. How fo I get rid of this?